# Have trouble linking my qt widget in qt designer to python

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, python-3.x, port

I'm new in python and pyqt.

I create small app for exam mode ports disabling. now i'm try to run in into gui app.where the the teacher clicks the button and the ports are disabled on the VLAN. my code is:

```
import os
# specify the command prompt command you need to be run
command = 'netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="BlockAIM" protocol=TCP dir=out remoteport=80 action=block'
# assign variable to the command
output = os.popen2(command)
# To get output call output.read()
```

this is the GUI

[image]

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: how do I make the button work to switch off the port 80 on a VLAN. @eyllanesc